# Why don't snapd app icons appear under GNOME/Wayland?

Tags: debian, gnome, wayland, snap, pureos

I am running PureOS (~= Debian testing) with a GNOME/Wayland desktop. After I install a program with snapd, I can run it from the command line with `snap run` but I can't launch it from the launcher, because the icon doesn't appear.

Is this a bug, a misconfiguration or am I missing a package?